# Kivy layout selection issue

Tags: user-interface, layout, kivy

I'm going to create a `Kivy` UI for my robot project, my only problem is working with layouts, I'm confused to it.

I'll attach GUI image that I want to create layout for it in `Kivy` please guide what is best choice (BOX, Grid, Relative,..) I know I must mix them and use 2 or more layout together but I can't select correctly, I read `Kivy` documentation and I tried to use `Kivy` Designer but still I couldn't choose best layouts. Maximum window size is 800x600.

[image: GUI 800x600]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer the SimpleTableLayout, it's a widget available in Kivy Garden:
[Simple Table Laout - Kivy Garden](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.simpletablelayout)

If you don't know how to use Kivy-Garden here are the installation instructions: [How to install kivy garden](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.garden.html)

The SimpleTableLayout supports row and column spanning as well as getting the widget of a certain cell: `SimpleTableLayout.cell(row, col)`

A little example for your App:

```
<SimpleTableLayout>:
    rows:10
    cols:14

    <Gauge1>:
        rowspan:2
        colspan:2

    <SpaceHolderWidget>:
        rowspan:12

    <SpaceHolderWidget>:
        colspan: 2

    <SmallGauge1>:

    <SpaceHolderWidget>:

    <SmallGauge2>:

    <SpaceHolderWidget>:
        colspan:2

    <SpaceHolderWidget>:
        rowspan:12

    <Gauge2>:
        rowspan:2
        colspan:2

    <Canvas>:
        rowspan:5
        colspan:7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know which layout to use, then use grid layout, because it's most versatile.

In general, if you want to put n widgets in a row, set `rows: 1`. If you want to put n widgets in a column, set `cols: 1`.

Then, manipulate `size_hint` to set correct size of a widget.

You can use blank labels to create spaces between widgets.

About Kivy Designer - it's better to first learn setting UI manually before using this tool.

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<RoundGauge@Button>:
    text: 'gauge'

<SidePanel@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    size_hint_x: .2

    RoundGauge:
        size_hint_y: .5
    RoundGauge:
        size_hint_y: .5

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        Slider:
            orientation: 'vertical'
        Slider:
            orientation: 'vertical'

# main layout divided into bottom gauges and screen part
GridLayout:
    cols: 1

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,.5
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    # both side panels and screen part
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        # left panel
        SidePanel:

        # middle panel
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1

            # upper gauges
            GridLayout:
                rows: 1
                size_hint_y: .3

                Label:
                RoundGauge:
                    size_hint_x: .5
                Label:
                    size_hint_x: .1
                RoundGauge:
                    size_hint_x: .5
                Label:

            Label:
                text: 'screen'
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1,1,1,.5
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos

            # bottom gauges
            GridLayout:
                rows: 1
                size_hint_y: .3

                RoundGauge:
                RoundGauge:
                RoundGauge:
                RoundGauge:
                RoundGauge:
                RoundGauge:

        # right panel
        SidePanel:

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        size_hint_y: .2

        RoundGauge:
        RoundGauge:
        RoundGauge:
        RoundGauge:
        RoundGauge:
        RoundGauge:
        RoundGauge:
```